# babel --presets only works with one preset

Tags: reactjs, npm, babeljs

I have installed babel-cli globally via npm, so in my working directory I installed babel-preset-react and babel-preset-env as dev dependencies. However, when I run the code `babel (path to the js file to be converted) --out-file=(path to the actual script that my index page uses) --presets=env,react`, I get a message in terminal which reads: "react doesn't exist". However, when I run the same code but include only react in --presets, it works.

So of course I tried running the same code but this time I listed react before env. This time it said "env doesn't exist". I'm baffled.

Comment: Please show the full output and error.

Comment: @loganfsmyth that IS the full output and error

Comment: Can you try `--presets env,react` without the `=`?

Comment: I tried it and the results are the same

Comment: have you tried using a `.babelrc` file instead?

Comment: no, but I want to know why this results in an error